# Cannot run SpringMVC/Hibernate CRUD on localhost

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat7

I am new into Spring/Hibernate, trying to set up a simple CRUD using SpringMVC/Hibernate following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKVYjJjNSak

Every time I run this app on my Tomcat 7 server, I get the following warning:

> Apr 07, 2017 3:38:16 AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl configure WARN:
>   HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : No suitable
>   driver found for jdbc.url

and what I get in my browser is:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
>   Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open
>   connection

when I enter the URL:
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCHibernateExample/customer/list

and when I enter these URLs, I get the following warnings:

in console I have:

> WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001 Apr 07, 2017 11:16:50 AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions ERROR:
>   No suitable driver found for jdbc.url Apr 07, 2017 11:16:50 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path
>   [/SpringMVCHibernateExample] threw exception [Request processing
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
>   Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open
>   connection] with root cause java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
>   found for jdbc.url    at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)  at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:450)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:450)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.listAllCustomers(Unknown Source)  at
>   springmvc_example.controller.CustomerController.list(CustomerController.java:26)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Apr 07, 2017 11:17:16 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound
>   noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/SpringMVCHibernateExample/] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'dispatcher'
>   Apr 07, 2017 11:19:43 AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions WARN:
>   SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001 Apr 07, 2017 11:19:43 AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions ERROR:
>   No suitable driver found for jdbc.url Apr 07, 2017 11:19:43 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path
>   [/SpringMVCHibernateExample] threw exception [Request processing
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
>   Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open
>   connection] with root cause java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
>   found for jdbc.url    at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)  at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:450)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:450)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.listAllCustomers(Unknown Source)  at
>   springmvc_example.controller.CustomerController.list(CustomerController.java:26)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I was fighting with issue for 5-6 hours(and two days before I was fighting with other issues in this project - which I already fixed, and not in last turn with the help of stackoverflow). Can anyone help me?

My pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>springmvc_example</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMVCHibernateExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>      
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
     <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>      
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
     <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>      
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
     <version>1.2</version>      
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.0</version>      
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
     <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>      
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
     <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>      
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
 </dependency>        
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
     <version>4.3.10.Final</version>      
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
     <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.0.Final</version>      
    </dependency>
  </dependencies> 
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is my config.properties:

```
jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springmvc/
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=nandri
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql = false
javax.persistence.validation.mode=none
```

my HibernateConfig.java class is:

```
package springmvc_example.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;



@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"springmvc_example.config"})
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:config.properties"})
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;


    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "springmvc_example.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc.url");
        dataSource.setUsername("jdbc.username");
        dataSource.setPassword("jdbc.password");
        return dataSource;
    }

    private  Properties hibernateProperties() {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));


        return properties;
    }


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(
            SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(
                s);
        return txManager;
    }



}
```

WebConfig.java:

```
package springmvc_example.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "springmvc_example")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{


    @Override
    public void  addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");

}


    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }



}
```

WebInitializer.java:

```
package springmvc_example.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {

        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {

        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

my model class - Customer.java

```
package springmvc_example.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;
  @Column(name="firstname")
  private String firstname;
  @Column(name="lastname")
  private String lastname;
  @Column(name="gender")
  private String gender;
  @Column(name="address")
  private String address;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}
public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}
public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}
```

DAO - CustomerDao.java:

```
package springmvc_example.dao;

import java.util.List;

import springmvc_example.model.Customer;

public interface CustomerDao {
   public List<Customer> listAllCustomers();

   public void saveOrUpdate(Customer customer);

   public Customer findCustomerById(int id);
   void deleteCustomer(int id);
}
```

DAO implementation -  CustomerDaoImpl.java:

```
package springmvc_example.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import springmvc_example.model.Customer;
@Repository
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private org.hibernate.Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Customer> listAllCustomers() {
        // Create CriteriaBuilder
        //CriteriaBuilder builder = getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();

        // Create CriteriaQuery
        //CriteriaQuery<Customer> criteria = builder.createQuery(Customer.class);
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Customer.class);
        return (List<Customer>) ((Criteria) criteria).list();
    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(Customer customer) {
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(customer);

    }

    public Customer findCustomerById(int id) {
        Customer customer = (Customer) getSession().get(Customer.class, id);
        return customer;
    }

    public void deleteCustomer(int id) {
        Customer customer = (Customer) getSession().get(Customer.class, id);
        getSession().delete(customer);
    }

}
```

Controller -  CustomerController.java:

```
package springmvc_example.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import springmvc_example.model.Customer;
import springmvc_example.service.CustomerService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/customer", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired
     CustomerService customerService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView list(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("customer/list");

        List<Customer> list = customerService.listAllCustomers();
        model.addObject("list", list);
        return model;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/update/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView update(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("customer/form");
        Customer customer = customerService.findCustomerById(id);

        model.addObject("customerForm", customer);
        return model;
    }



    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView add(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("customer/form");
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        model.addObject("customerForm", customer);
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("customerForm") Customer customer){
        customerService.saveOrUpdate(customer);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/customer/list");
    }

}
```

The structure of the project is the following:pom.xml is in

> C:\Users\Jeddid\workspace\SpringMVCHibernateExample

JSPs are in:

> C:\Users\Jeddid\workspace\SpringMVCHibernateExample\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jsp\customer

config.properties is in

> C:\Users\Jeddid\workspace\SpringMVCHibernateExample\src\main\resources

HibernateConfig.java, WebConfig.java and WebInitializer.java are in

> C:\Users\Jeddid\workspace\SpringMVCHibernateExample\src\main\java\springmvc_example\config

and the rest of the .java classes are in the corresponding folders(i.e.model is in

> C:\Users\Jeddid\workspace\SpringMVCHibernateExample\src\main\java\springmvc_example\model

,
controller is in

> C:\Users\Jeddid\workspace\SpringMVCHibernateExample\src\main\java\springmvc_example\controller

,CustomerService.java and CustomerServiceImpl.java are in servive, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/SpringMVCHibernateExample/customer]

it is because, You have mapped it to /customer/list, you should try

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCHibernateExample/customer/list
```

> Update:

Answer to your Question in the comment
Change Your jdbc.url to the following:

> (1) remove / at the end (2) remove the spaces before and after =

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springmvc
```

Comment: proposed changes(removing / and spaces) didn't give any result